# How do I run a parse.com function using jquery

Tags: jquery, parse-platform, jscript

I'm using parse.com and javascript/jquery.

I have the following block of code that saves the current user to the parse.com backend.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function saveprofile(){
      alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
      var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
              currentUser.save(null, {
            success: function(object) {
                // The object was saved successfully.
                console.log("User updated!");
                            }
        });
});
});
```

Im using the js plugin jeditable http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable that lets you edit html elements directly in the page.

It currently uses

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });
```

to save the changes back to a php database, of course I want to swap this out so it runs for parse.com, I thought I could just call my **saveprofile** function,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('saveprofile');
 });
```

but this doesn't work. What do I need to amend to make it work please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared that saveprofile function correctly?

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();     
function saveprofile() {
    currentUser.save(null, {            
        success: function(object) {
            console.log("User updated!");           
        }       
    });    
} // saveprofile()


$('.edit').editable('saveprofile');
```

Comment: @grameboy Thanks, I updated my code on your answer, but still get the following error

POST http://kudosoo.com/saveprofile 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:2
send jquery.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery.js:2
(anonymous function) jeditable.mini.js:24
p.event.dispatch jquery.js:2
g.handle.h

Any idea?